# Can I type on multiple Excel cells simultaneously, not copying the entire cell, but just typing on certain parts of each cell

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2016

I am dealing with a task that involves repetition in the values of cells, not the entire cell but only on a certain part of it.
In this [image: screenshot]

I highlighted in pink the values that are similar, from top cell to bottom. The yellow ones would be similar as the last part of each cell from left to right.

I could easily copy the cell from to top to bottom to duplicate the pink highlighted values. But for the yellow ones, I was thinking that if I could place my insertion point in multiple cells at a time, I could type them all at the same time on the last part of each cells while retaining the pink highlighted values.

My current workaround is to copy the cells onto VSCode and do the edits there, where it's possible to have multiple insertion points at once. Like [image: here].

Comment: Ususally I would either try a search/replace to do it, or save as CSV and edit the CSV in a text editor.

Comment: To my knowledge, excel does not support typing into multiple cells concurrently. You would need helper cells or a VBA script to approximate that feature.

Comment: Perhaps if there is a structure to the components in your formula, then you could build a formula to build your formula...hope that made sense.